# WinError 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host when sending an email with attachment through Gmail API with Python

Tags: gmail-api

Trying to send an email with an attachment through Gmail API using Python.

When sending an email without an attachment, everything works fine, but once I add PDF file, Google returns me "[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

Does anyone have an idea why this happening?

My code:

```
import base64
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from httplib2 import Http

def auth(scopes):
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', scopes)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
    return service

def create_mess():
    message = MIMEText('Message text')
    message['to'] = 'to@gmail.com'
    message['from'] = 'from@domain.com'
    message['subject'] = 'Subject'
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode()}

def create_mess_att():
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['to'] = 'to@gmail.com'
    message['from'] = 'from@domain.com'
    message['subject'] = 'Subject'

    msg = MIMEText('Message text')
    message.attach(msg)

    fp = open('TestFile.pdf', 'rb')
    msg = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    msg.set_payload(fp.read())
    fp.close()

    filename = 'TestFile.pdf'
    msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
    message.attach(msg)

    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode()}

def send_mess(message):
    service.users().messages().send(userId='me', body=message).execute()
```

This part does works:

```
service = auth('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify')
message = create_mess()
send_mess(message)
```

This part does not:

```
service = auth('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify')
message = create_mess_att()
send_mess(message)

ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Thanks in advance!